# HTML5 Canvas function to rotate object

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, matrix

I am currently in the process of doing some translations on an aeroplane I have created on HTML5/JavaScript.
I have a matrix class, a class for my aeroplane and a main class.
So far I have gotten my scale and translate to work however I am struggling to get the rotate to work.

Here is the code in the matrix class which creates the rotation:

```
     Matrix.createRotation = function (rotation) {
    return new Matrix(Math.cos(rotation), -Math.sin(rotation), 0,
                      Math.sin(rotation), Math.cos(rotation), 0,
                      0, 0, 1);
};
```

and the Transform in the matrix class:

```
 Matrix.prototype.transform = function (pContext) {
    pContext.transform(this.getElement(0, 0), this.getElement(1, 0), this.getElement(0, 1),
    this.getElement(1, 1), this.getElement(0, 2), this.getElement(1, 2));
};
```

I know there is nothing wrong with them because it passed there unit test.

Here is the method used to rotate the object

```
 function rotate() {
    var matrix = Matrix.createRotation(Math.PI);
    matrix.setTransform(mainContext);
};
```

And here is where I call it:

```
  initialiseCanvasContext();
scale(new Vector(1, 1));
drawPlane(new Vector(0, 0));
rotate();
```

Sorry if this is confusing, please let me know if it is.

Comment: Have you tried rotating *before* drawing the plane?

Comment: I suppose it depends on how you're applying the transforms to the canvas and, may be a problem later, if you're multiplying your "scale" matrix by the "rotation" matrix to get a combined effect.

Comment: You must multiply the matrices to create one matrix. Translate * Scale * Rotation matrices to get the matrix to apply to the prop. But without knowing what library you are using it is hard top give you precise advice.

Comment: Did you mean to use transform() instead of setTransform() inside the rotate() function? As of now the transform doesn't gets accumulated, but sets a new each time.